# libstdc++.so.5: cannot open shared object file - but library is installed and up-to-date

Tags: linux, fedora, libstdc++

My client had some developer write a small c++ command-line app to run on their Linux servers.   On one of the servers (running Fedora 11), when I execute the app I get the following error:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Obviously the first thing I did was

```
yum install libstdc++
```

But I get

```
Package libstdc++-4.4.1-2.fc11.x86_64 already installed and latest version
```

So the library already exists and is up-to-date. Usually to me these errors indicate a missing library. So where should I look next?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`libstdc++-4.4.1-2.fc11.x86_64` installs `libstdc++.so.6`. You need the `compat-libstdc++-33-3.2.3-66.x86_64` package to get `libstdc++.so.5`. (Do not symlink! `libstdc++.so.5` and  `libstdc++.so.6` are incompatible.)

Answer (score 14):

rpm hence the repo knows about shared library names and what provides them. So

```
yum install 'libstdc++.so.5'
```

wiil install whatever is necessary if the repo has it.

In your case it would fetch compat-libstdc++-33-3.2.3-66.i586.rpm and its 32-bit deps if you don't have them already because the binary you are trying to run is apparently 32-bit

Answer (score 7):

yum install compat-libstdc++-33 solved this for me.

Answer (score 3):

libstdc++.so.5 is a very old version of the standard c++ library.

Do a `yum search libstdc++` , you'll have to install one of the compat-libstdc++ packages.

Answer (score 1):

As stated by caf and aaron, running `yum install compat-libstdc++-33 libstdc++.so.5 -y` worked for me when I got a similar error.

The only catch I ran into was, I didn't have the correct repo checked out so I had to run `yum-config-manager --enable rhel-7-server-optional-rpms` to access the files. If you are using something other than RedHat 7 you will need to search for the correct repo.

You could always check if you have the correct repo by running `yum provides libstdc++.so.5` first.

Answer (score 0):

worked for me too on RedHat 7 : error was :

> error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.5: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32

The solution was  :
`yum install compat-libstdc++-33 libstdc++.so.5 -y`

Answer (score -1):

Have you checked that the package does install libstdc++.so.5 and not some other version? That's your most likely problem.

Comment: This does not answer the question. This should be a comment.